# How to make vue-router mode history work with laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I currently have a SPA using Vuejs VueRouter and Laravel. What I am trying to do is to make the experience as smooth as possible for the user. I have laravel routes as well as vue routes defined. The currently problem I am facing is that when I set mode: history and then refresh the page. It shows the data as json.

Lets say I hit this endpoint:

localhost:8080/user

The page will show as expected (Vue component in this case)

But if I refresh the page, it will show this:

```
user {

name: "test",
id: "1"

}
```

This is the vue routes I have

```
import User from './components/user/User';

export default {
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/user',
            name: 'user',
            component: User
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the laravel routes I have

```
Route::get('user', 'UserController@index');


Route::get('/{any}', 'AppController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

This is the app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';
import App from './components/App';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        App
    },
    router: new VueRouter(routes)
});
```

How will I be able to still show the vue component on page refresh and not what the method returns from the backend

Comment: Can you please add screen short app.js file ?

Comment: just updated it

Comment: It's not possible if both your laravel and vue routes clash.

Comment: @Viney not possible? Then how does vue-router and laravel work together?? How can someone build a SPA using both

Answer (score 0):

try this in app.js

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
let routes = [
     { path: '/Users', component: require('./components/Users.vue').default},
]
const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes
 })
```

if you need add component just create it and then refer to it like that 
and don't forget to refer router on the #app like that

```
const app = new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     router
});
```

Finally Check The Console For Any Other Errors

Comment: I added my app.js in my question

Comment: just try these and tell me